# Retrieve a row from a cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This should be simple, I can't find a way to do it :

I want to loop through all the rows of a table using a cursor and I need ALL the columns of the row :

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM Table_1 order by l1;

DECLARE rr ROW for cursor1;     /*does not work */

OPEN cursor1;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 into rr;    /*does not work */

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Centres 
    VALUES(rr.l1, rr.l2, rr.l3)    /*does not work because of rr */

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 into rr;    /*does not work */
END;

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
GO
```

Unfortunately, I cannot declare a variable that is row type of my cursor... or can I ?

Comment: Currently what you have can be accomplished without a cursor (INSERT+SELECT), which are things you should avoid wherever possible ...

Comment: You need to use variable for a cursor. But more to the point is you do NOT need a cursor here. This is nothing more than a single insert statement. Using a cursor here is forcing it to go a lot slower than it could.

Comment: For each column returned by the cursor, declare a variable of the appropriate type. Then use `FETCH NEXT FROM <CURSOR> INTO @col1, @col2, ... @colN`. But as others have pointed out, your task can be accomplished without a cursor.

Comment: ok guys, just suppose i need to do conditionnal things through all this, because of course i admit that what i posted didn't requires any... but @TT. answered the question, i have to declare all the vars, i cannot declare any ROWTYPE variable

Comment: You should describe the conditions and see if anyone can suggest a set based (non-cursor) approach

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have any concept of `ROWTYPE` - if you have 10 columns in your row, you need to define **10 separate, explicit variables** for each of these columns. No way around this - other than just forgetting about the cursor altogether and doing it in a much more desirable **set-based** fashion instead!

Comment: Please abandon this cursor based code.  Please.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Do you have enough input to proceed with your task? Or shall I type out an example based on your script in the question?

Comment: No ! dont borther yourself anymore, i already have the answer, just post it as an answer if you want me to accept it. And i know everyone hates the row by row concept but it's not like i'm coding anything important, this is to be used only once so no matter how it's done... it's done, all's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as a `Row` type in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

I already mentioned not needing a cursor but you also should ALWAYS specify columns in an insert. Your entire cursor could be reduced to a simple insert statement along these lines.

```
Insert Centres(l1, l2, l3)
select l1, l2, l3
from Table_1
```